# how to pass user_id from login page into two different page such as ownerpage for user and owner product

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

For the Login page, I am using:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: _login,
  color: Colors.red,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
  child: Text('Login'),
```

Then the part for checking in the MySQL. I am still new to flutter, so I tried the to use `navigator.pushreplacename` to try to push data into two type of page, but it return a page that have `null` value.

```
Future<List> _login() async{
final response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2/foodsystem/login.php", body: {
  "username": user.text,
  "password": pass.text,
});

var datauser = json.decode(response.body);

if(datauser.length==0){
  setState(() {
    msg="Login Fail";
  });
}else{
  if(datauser[0]['level']=='1'){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
  }else if(datauser[0]['level']=='2'){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/OwnerPage',);
    //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/produt');
  }
  else if(datauser[0]['level']=='3'){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/MemberPage');
  }

  setState(() {
    username= datauser[0]['username'];
    user_id= datauser[0]['user_id'];


  });



}
return datauser;
```

The route that I am used to changing the screen:

```
routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
    '/AdminPage': (BuildContext context)=> new AdminPage(username: username,),
    '/MemberPage': (BuildContext context)=> new MemberPage(username: username,),
    '/OwnerPage': (BuildContext context)=> new OwnerPage(username: username, user_id: user_id,),
    //'/produt': (BuildContext context)=> new ProductFood(username: username, user_id: user_id,),
    '/MyHomePage': (BuildContext context)=> new MyHomePage(),
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I used to store user information (id, token, username, avatar, ...) in cache after login, then you can access it from anywhere.
- If don't want to cache it, you can just declare a global files and save it there:

```
//globals.dart

library my_prj.globals; 
...
var userId;
```

And in your login file,

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals

...
setState((){
   globals.userId = userId;
});
```

You can access the userId wherever you want by importing the globals.dart

Answer (score 0):

On Login Page write,

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/ownerPage',
  arguments: {
    "user_id" : user_id
  }
);
```

On Owner/Member page write,
Inside the build method,

> remember, this is not a class level implementation i.e you do not
> require route properties in this case

```
Map data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Now the data will have all your passed.